# Vue.js preselect first element in select field?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using museUI for a select input. When I try to make the first item in the dropdown as the default I can't make it work. How do I preselect the first item on the array that populates the v-for:

This is how my template looks:

```
  <mu-select-field v-model="selectModel">
    <mu-menu-item v-for="text,index in dropdown"  :key="index" :value="index" :title="text"/>
  </mu-select-field>
```

And my script:

```
  export default Vue.component('st-filter', {
    data () {
      return {
        selectModel: "",
        dropdown : [],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      populateDates: function () {
        let date7daysAgo, date1monthAgo...
        this.dropdown = [`Last week (${date7daysAgo} - ${dateToday})`, `Last month (${date7daysAgo} - ${date1monthAgo})` ];
        this.selectModel = this.dropdown[0];

      }
    },
    created() {
      this.populateDates();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok found solution here: http://www.muse-ui.org/#/selectField

Just had to assign selected to 0 and remove the assign in the populateDates method like ths:

```
  export default Vue.component('st-filter', {
    data () {
      return {
        selectModel: 0, //<=== Assign = 0
        dropdown : [],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      populateDates: function () {
        let date7daysAgo, date1monthAgo...
        this.dropdown = [`Last week (${date7daysAgo} - ${dateToday})`, `Last month (${date7daysAgo} - ${date1monthAgo})` ];
        // ERASE this: ====> this.selectModel = this.dropdown[0];

      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I googled the entire internet for a solution and out of a sudden it stuck me...
Now with the Composition API you use either ref() or reactive({}) in combination with the v-model and there you can set the value.
So, in my case I knew the id I wanted to set to be pre-selected:

```
      <label for="myoptions">{{ $t('options') }}</label>
      <select id="myoptions" v-model="options.category" class="form-select">
        <option v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id" :value="category.id">
          {{ category.name }}
        </option>
      </select>
```

In my case I wanted to set the option with the id of 2 to be the pre-selected:

```
    <script setup lang="ts">   
    ...  
    const {categories, error} = storeToRefs(useStore())
   
    const options = reactive<whatever>({
    ...
    category: '2'
    ...

    })
```